# Old Scalabium Software's SMDBFltr thows an AV in Delphi 11.2 64 bits

Tags: delphi

Old Scalabium Software's SMDBFltr throws an AV in Delphi 11.2 64 bits but not in 32 bits application.
Debug points to this line:

```
function TSMDBFilterDialog.GetCurrentFilter: string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not Assigned(frmFilterDialog) then
    Exit;
  for i := 0 to frmFilterDialog.lbFilter.Items.Count-1 do
    Result := Result + PAnsiString(frmFilterDialog.lbFilter.Items[i].Data)^;  {<<-- AV here}
  if (Result <> '') then
    Result := ' AND ' + Result;

  if (Result <> '') then
    Result := Copy(Result, 6, Length(Result)-5);
end;
```

but I can't figure out what's wrong!

It works in Delphi 10.4 in both 32 and 64 bits.
Any idea of  what's wrong?
Best Regards
Francisco Alvarado

Resolved
Thanks to AmigoJack and Brian for pointing the ASLR issue and thanks to Mike Shkolnik from scalabium for his help. The problem was resolved changing bigInt to NativeInt types.
Sorry for not being explicit

Comment: As per [smcmpnt.zip\SOURCES\SMDBFltr.pas](http://www.scalabium.com/smdbfltr.htm) lines like `ListItem.Data := TObject(LongInt(NewStr(strCondition)));` look highly suspicious: in 64bit `LongInt` remains 32bit and will truncate the 64bit Pointer (`PAnsiString`). Change every use of that [into `NativeInt`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Platform-Dependent_Integer_Types). Or contact Scalabium.

Comment: Note Delphi 11.2 turns on more ASLR features for the executables it produces. This makes it much more likely 64 bit pointers will not have the top 32 bits all zeroes  See answer to this question for more detail : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74508190/delphi-11-2-createwindowex-fails-thread-on-x64