# What changes are needed to get this timer to work under Delphi Alexandria 64 bit?

Tags: delphi, timer

The violation occurs at the line "Suspended" in the callback. The timer component is the SVATimer.pas that I've used for years with good, accurate results. It does still run under Rio, but not Alexandria.

```pascal
procedure MMTimerCallBack(TimerID, Msg: Uint; dwUser, dw1, dw2: DWORD); stdcall;
begin
  with TSVATimerThread(dwUser) do
    if Suspended then begin
      TimeKillEvent(FTimerID);
      FTimerID:= 0
    end
    else
      Synchronize(FOwner.DoTimerProc)
end;

procedure TSVATimerThread.Execute;
begin
  repeat
    FTimerID:= TimeSetEvent(FInterval, 0, @MMTimerCallBack, cardinal(Self), TIME_PERIODIC);
    if FTimerID <> 0 then    
      WaitForSingleObject(FEvent, INFINITE);
    if FTimerID <> 0 then
      TimeKillEvent(FTimerID)
  until Terminated
end;
```

Comment: (1) `Cardinal(Self)` must be `NativeInt(Self)`. (2) `dwUser, dw1, dw2` must be `DWORD_PTR`. Please note that this code has *never* been correct on 64-bit. It has only worked by accident. Essentially, this Q is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/74508271/282848. Also, please note that you could have figured out all this by yourself had you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff728861(v=vs.85)).

Comment: I'm sorry to have appeared so ignorant. There is much I do not know, it seems. Thank you, those changes worked.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*`Cardinal(Self)` must be `NativeInt(Self)`*" - actually, it should be `DWORD_PTR(Self)` to match the API.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I saw that after five minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is a 32-bit value in a 32-bit build, and a 64-bit value in a 64-bit build.  However, you are passing around your `Self` pointer as a 32-bit value regardless of the build type, so it gets truncated in a 64-bit build.

You need to fix your declaration of `MMTimerCallBack()` and the call to `TimeSetEvent()`, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757634(v=vs.85)), so that you are passing the pointer correctly in both build types, eg:

```
procedure MMTimerCallBack(TimerID, Msg: UINT; dwUser, dw1, dw2: DWORD_PTR); stdcall;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure TSVATimerThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  FTimerID := TimeSetEvent(..., @MMTimerCallBack, DWORD_PTR(Self), ...);
  ...
end;
```