# CreateWindowEx() Returns 0

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

I know that there are many posts regarding my issue, I also read this post
[Delphi 11.2: CreateWindowEx fails thread on x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74508190/delphi-11-2-createwindowex-fails-thread-on-x64)
but I am not able to understand what exactly I should do to overcome this problem. I am working on Cromis.DirectoryMonitoring Cromis.Utils.pas https://github.com/CPsoftBE/BackupOfCromis, below code CreateWindowEx() Returns 0 only for Delphi 11.2 / 64Bit.

```
Result := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, CTSHiddenWindowName, '', WS_POPUP,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, nil);
```

Comment: Does calling [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) produce any useful insight?

Comment: Most likely [`RegisterClass( CTSHiddenWindowName )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassa) was not called, which is needed for [`CreateWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) as the manual explains.

Comment: @AmigoJack the code in question is calling `RegisterClass()`. Another possibility is that the registered `WndProc` for the `CTSHiddenWindowName` class has a bug in it that is causing the window creation to be aborted. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the failure in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see in `Cromis.Utils.pas` is that the declaration of `TSClassWndProc()` is wrong for a 64bit build.  It is declaring as this:

```pascal
function TSClassWndProc(Window: HWND; Message, WParam, LParam: longint): longint; stdcall;
```

`Longint` is the wrong type to use.  The function should be declared as this instead:

```pascal
function TSClassWndProc(Window: HWND; Message: UINT; WParam: WPARAM; LParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
```

The size of `WPARAM`, `LPARAM`, and `LRESULT` vary between 32bit and 64bit builds.  Using the wrong types can cause *undefined behavior*.

---

On a side note, there is no need to use an `{$IFDEF}` to conditionally call `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr()` vs `(Get|Set)WindowLong()` based on build target.  `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr()` work in both 32bit and 64bit builds, so use them unconditionally.

Comment: Replacing as advised    ...TSClassWndProc(Window: HWND; ....  resolved the problem. Earlier Result := CreateWindowEx( ... was returning 0 without throwing any exception, now it returns valid result. Thank You.